# Scripts loaded with LABjs are still blocking

Tags: javascript, labjs

Here is an example: http://ci.elfster.com/core/login.aspx

Look at the net tab in Firebug and you will see that scripts still have a substantial blocking period.

Does anybody have a working example that shows ten scripts downloading in parallel without blocking using LABjs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to `about:config` and setting `network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server higher`

My guess is that yours is still set to 6 and that is why the downloads are blocking.

Comment: (Or two, which was the default not-too-long ago :p)

Comment: ok I talked to the LABjs dude and he confirmed this too. It was my understanding that you could load as many scripts as you want without blocking but now I understand that there is a browser limit to this concept. consolidating my scripts now